What are the ideals of the group ring $\Bbb Z_p[\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z]$?
Let $p$ be an odd prime. Write $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to denote the ring of $p$-adic integers and set $G=\mathbb{Z}/p$. Is there a way to write explicitly what are all the ideals of the group ring $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$?

What are your thoughts and ideas, and what is the background of this question?

You don't say why you require $p > 2$. Anyway, when $R$ is a commutative ring and $G$ is cyclic of order $n$, $R[G] \cong R[x]/(x^n - 1)$. Watch out: the Chinese remainder theorem does not work in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ or $\mathbf Z[x]$ in the same way it does in $K[x]$ when $K$ is a field, e.g., $\mathbf Z_2[x]/(x^2-1) \not\cong \mathbf Z_2 \times \mathbf Z_2$ as rings since their mod $2$ reductions are not isomorphic.

The question came up related to my research and it appeared to me that this might be known but searching Google and Mathscinet did not help much. Of course, the augmentation ideal is one.

For what is worth, your ring is isomorphic to the subring of $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$ consisting of pairs $(a,z)$ such that $a\equiv z  \mod (1-\zeta_p)$. I don't know if it is really helpful, though...
